# Excel: match date and find next value after, return date from that row

Tags: excel

I have the following Spreadsheet.

```
A1:A1000 = Dates (in date order) 
B1:B1000 = Values (in date order)
C1 = Date I want to look up 
D1 = Value I want to look up
F1= //Answer
```

I want to look for C1 in Column A and then from that row look down for a value <= D1 and then return the Date from that row in Column A to F1.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

```
Date           Price           Date to find      Value 
24/9/1999       3.58             8/10/1999        3.55
1/10/1999       3.72
8/10/1999       3.57
15/10/1999      3.65
22/10/1999      3.62
29/10/1999      3.68
5/11/1999       3.66
12/11/1999      3.61
19/11/1999      3.50
```

Result should be 19/11/1999

Comment: I would think MINIFS() would work, but without test data it is difficult to know for certain: `=MINIFS(A1:A1000,A1:A1000,">="&C1,B1:B1000,"<="&D1)`

Comment: @Scott Craner.  Thanks for that.  It just seems to return the value in C1.  I've tried to add some data, but I don't think I was too successful.

Comment: With your data and the formula above I get `19/11/1999` returned.

Comment: Did you have `"<="&D1` instead of `">="&D1`  Which is the only way you would get `8/10/1999` with that data set.

Comment: @Scott Craner.  Thank you very much, that works.  Not sure what I was doing wrong the first time.  Much appreciated

Comment: Maybe.  I could be accused of being a bit, copy and paste, happy. :)  Hides the mistakes and lots of good stuff.